# Server Side Rendering is not working in CCV2 Cloud

Tags: spartacus-storefront

We are using Spartacus Version 3.0.0 and have setup Cloud Deployment via SAP CCV2 Cloud.

We followed the steps to enable SSR described in https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/server-side-rendering-in-spartacus/#adding-ssr-support-using-schematics-recommended. Additionally we  also followed the guide for the workaround needed regarding the file structure in CCV2 cloud: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/ssr-ccv2-issue-spartacus-version-2/#page-title

So far, all works locally when starting the server both in dev and production mode. As soon as we deploy into the CCV2 Cloud, we don't have Server Side rendering at all anymore.

In the Kibana log, we sometimes see the error message "SSR Rendering exceeded timeout, fallbacking to CSR", but only for some requests occasionally, which means, that for most requests, there is no SSR, but also no error logs..

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the IP Restriction on the DEV environment of CCV2. This IP Restriction is currently also being applied for the request coming from the Storefront Service during an SSR Request, as the ip of the storefront service was not whitelisted, the call always returned a 403, what was returning as a SSR timeout.

The spartacus documentation has been update regarding that problem: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/server-side-rendering-optimization/#troubleshooting-a-storefront-that-is-not-running-in-ssr-mode

We have created an SAP Bug ticket to fix that problem.